# Order master detail for the web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that I need to create and not sure how to go about doing the front end.

I have two tables, `oders` and `order_details` (master/detail) I need to somehow create a couple of search fields, send the query out to the server bring back the orders and display them in a grid type of view.

When the user clicks on one of these rows, I can go back to the server, say with the order id, grab the `order_details` records and display them in the bottom somehow.

I can do `json`, can also return java result sets, but I'm not sure how to go about doing the frontend.. if anybody can point me to `jquery` examples, or anything along those lines it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For front end I would start at looking at web forms http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: When you list orders, it is usually no more than 30, so go on and gather all the orders details together with orders - no need to use ajax at all. At the end, hide order details and show them on click.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have database tables:

```
order(orderid, date, total)
order_details(id, orderid, products)
```

than your index.php file may look like this:

```
<?php
switch( $_POST['action'] ) {
    case 'get_orders':
        /* you need to create this function (func_query), it would return an array of MySQL result set */
        $orders = func_query("select * from orders");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($orders);
        exit();
        break;
    case 'get_order_details':
        $order_details = func_query("select * from orders_details where orderid=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['orderid']));
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($order_details);
        exit();
        break;
};
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Orders</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('ready', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {'action': 'get_orders'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('.orders_list').html('');
                        var orders_list_html = '';
                        if ( data.length>0 ) {
                            orders_list_html += '<ul>';
                            $.each( data, function(i, order) {
                                orders_list_html += '<li data-orderid="' + order.orderid + '">' + order.date + ', ' + order.total + '</li>';
                            });
                            orders_list_html += '<ul>';
                            $('.orders_list').html( orders_list_html );
                        };
                    }
                });
                $('.orders_list').on('click', 'li[data-orderid]', function(e) {
                    var thisList = $(this);
                    var orderid = thisList.data('orderid');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {'action': 'get_order_details', 'orderid': orderid},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            /* Do something with data, append to thisList or show it somewhere */
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your orders</h1>
        <div class="orders_list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Haven't tested it, but you can get the idea.